# How to get historical/archived transactions by wallet address?

Tags: transactions, archive-node

Sorry in advance if this is covered elsewhere, I wasn't able to find it.

I need to get all transactions related to my wallet address, most of which happened in 2022 before the merge. What is the best way to do this?

- Run a geth local node and use Admanant-im. But, I don't have enough local HDD space to run a full archival node. Can I run one and define the timeframe it contains (Jan 1/22 - present)?
- Use Google's Bigquery. Supposedly it has the entire ethereum chain available to query. But, I don't know SQL and was hoping someone could help me out with the query I would need to run.

So many thanks in advance!!
Al